# Golang package api design: pass pointer parameter or value

Tags: go, api-design

I'm writing a new package in Go, to work with money (I'm aware that other packages already do this).

An essential type is `Money`:

```
type Money struct {
  // Factional value of the monetary value.
  Cents int
  // ISO code of the currency of the monetary value.
  Currency string
  bank     *Bank
}
```

Now I have to define a method `m.ExchangeTo(currency)` that exchanges money to another currency.

The question is: what is the best signature for this method?

Some proposals:

#### Receiver and return value are pointers

```
func (m *Money) ExchangeTo(toCurrency string) *Money
```

#### Receiver and return value are structs

```
func (m Money) ExchangeTo(toCurrency string) Money
```

#### No return value, ExchangeTo change the receiver value (side effect)

```
func (m *Money) ExchangeTo(toCurrency string)
```

I know this depends on what you have to do, but this is a general-purpose package, so I'm looking for some advice.

Comment: I wouldn't put this method in `Money` (why would a value/data object know about conversion rates?). With that said, I generally find it easier to work with values instead of pointers (unless some requirements call for using pointers). I never use the mutating/side-effect version for transformations like this.

Comment: "what is the best signature for this method", well, "the best" is hard to tell. It all depends. All have benefits and drawbacks and weighting them is your job.

Comment: One more which might make googleing related stuff easier: Passing a pointer in Go is not "pass by reference". Actually pointers are not references at all (except for those people who insist calling a pointer a reference).

Comment: I'd rather make conversion a function of the bank, since in the same country different banks can have different exchange rate.

Comment: Effective go and Go Wiki have interesting sections on this topis: https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#methods and https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-type

Comment: Also, the side-effect option reminds me of javascript moment's API, whose objects are mutable. Mutability can be a great source of confusion and moment's doc appears to acknowledge that on it's "Project Status" page.